# Where can I find FragmentTabHost Library

Tags: android, fragment

Ok, so this is what I get to see when I'm missing the library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
```

Where can I find it and how do I need to add this library to my project?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK\extras\android\support\v4`, if this lib doesnt help, update your sdk view sdk manager

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse: right click on your project > Android Tools > Add Support Library...

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 0):

Either way you could do the following.
In your SDK folder go to-
android-sdk >> extras >> android >> support >> v4
Copy that library and paste it in the "libs" folder of your android project.

Well, you can check it by right clicking on your android project and clicking on "Properties".
Click on Java Build Path >> Android Dependencies